# Make WTSQuerySessionInformation and/or %CLIENTNAME% work during loginskript?

Tags: windows, authentication, remote-desktop

For users logging in to a Windows 2008 R2 Remote Desktop Server, I need to know the name of the client PC. As I learned the hard way, it seems that `WTSQuerySessionInformation()` does not work properly during the execution of login skripts. I've seen it return the name the user logged in from the day before, for example. Remarkably, the function itself never failed (as in: return false), it merely "lied". A quick cross-check revealed that the environment variable `%CLIENTNAME%` is not set during the execution of login skripts either (though I only observed it *empty*, not *wrong* in my handful of tests).

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19428951/wtsquerysessioninformation-is-failing-on-windows-server-2008-r2) info about problems during logoff cause the (lengthy) logoff may take place with the session closing already handled.
But the way I understand it, the session is established before the login process even begins, so it seems strange that the session information is not yet available. Apparently I am wrong, so my question is:

**Q:** How can I find out the name of the client PC (or at least its IP) during login?

Alternatively: **Q:** How can I execute a program in the user context as soon as his SessionInformation gets set to its correct value?

(An answer to the alternative question might even be more interesting as it could also deal with the case of a user "stealing" his active session from another client)

Comment: I would hazard a guess that applications and scripts launched via the [Run registry key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376977(v=vs.85).aspx) will have that information available to them.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Sonunds good so far. At least from *experiments* it *seems* that "Run" is executed after "login" and therefore has a biggre *chance* that the seesion information has been updated. This all seems to be a bit vague, especially because I cannot *force* the original problem to appear, i.e. most of the time WTSQuerySessionInformation returns the correct answer ... Is there any info that turns this experimental knowledge into confirmed knowledge?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Meanwhile I found some discussions that a GPO "Run these programs *after* logon" should help. Actually, there exists only a GPO setting "Run these programs *at* logon" and that seems to be equivalent to HKCU/.../Run I'll try that in my live environment and suggest you make an answer from your comment (maybe including the above)

Comment: I am using `WTSRegisterSessionNotification` from a service to get notified about a new logon and start a process in the user's session. Though from your problem description I currently doubt it would solve your problem because the notification is probably emitted before programs listed under HKCU/.../Run are executed. I didn't verify this, so you may want to give it a try nevertheless.